# Literature on discriminant analysis

Tags: statistics, machine-learning

Can anyone suggest a good book on discriminant analysis - comprehensible and detailed? (Kendall and Stuart write about the subject too concisely.)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You might get more helpful answers if you tell us your math and stat background, and the kinds of applications you have in mind. Huge or moderate sample sizes? Nearly normal or clearly non-normal data? Almost no missing data, or messy data as from scraping the web?

Comment: My math and stat background is decent. I want to get a dataset suitable for a relatively easy bachelor thesis in statistics, data should be close to normal, sample size - ideally moderate (and preferably no missing data). In summary - almost an example from a textbook :).  So far I haven't found a textbook in English on discriminant analysis which is both mathematically rigorous and comprehensible and doesn't require a substantial knowledge of ANOVA or other topics of multivariate analysis.

Answer (score 0):

Extended comment:

Linear discriminant analysis is a topic in 'multivariate analysis'.
If you google that topic for 'books' you will see, among other
things, a couple of pages on our associated site 'crossvalidated'
dealing with recommendations of books in the field. Take a look
to see which ones contain chapters on 'discriminant analysis'.

Modern books on multivariate statistics do not seem to focus
as much on discriminant analysis as older ones did. 'Cluster analysis' is not
exactly the same thing, but a related topic. Maybe your first
task is to find out if there is a related topic in multivariate
analysis that is of equal or greater interest to you. Perhaps
with online datasets and modern software to match.

Discriminant analysis was invented by R.A. Fisher. He illustrated
the key ideas with his now-famous dataset on iris flowers: 
petal and sepal lengths and widths for three species of
irises. The question is whether it is possible to DISCRIMINATE
among the three species using only these four measurements.
That is NOT just asking whether, for example, data indicate that
sepal widths have different species population means. It is asking whether the
sepal widths differ enough that you can identify which of the three species
a particular flower belongs to just knowing its sepal width. (The answer
is NO, but if you consider all four measurements in 4-space,
you can almost make an ID without error.)

Given the computational limitation of his time (1920s, I believe),
Fisher took some shortcuts. It might be a worthwhile (although
certainly not original) senior project to do a modern discriminant
analysis of the iris data using R or some other statistical
package. The iris dataset is of moderate size and has no
missing data--as you specified.

Some years ago I published a book 'Learning Statistics with Real
Data' in which one chapter used an older version of Minitab
to do a somewhat more modern discriminant analysis of the iris
data than Fisher's. (I say 'somewhat', because the Minitab procedure
available then made some assumptions that aren't quite true.)
The book is out of print (used copies on Amazon for \$5-\$10), but if you google my faculty profile
to get my contact info, I can email you a .pdf of the chapter.

There is an inexpensive Google-Sage book on discriminant
analysis by Klecka (1980) with editorial collaborators I know.
But I have not looked at it. Given the date, I do not suppose
you will get much help there with computation or large datasets,
but it might be a good orientation.

I also noticed there is a You Tube demo on discriminant analysis
using R. At least the price is right.

The modern computationally oriented books I have seen on
discriminant analysis seem to assume you already know what it
is and just want to know how to run a particular computer
program.

Your faculty adviser should give you some guidance as to the
subject and level of your project. Statistics, linear algebra,
graphics, and computation all play roles in discriminant
analysis. I won't make specific recommendations because I
don't know enough of your background, requirements of such
a project, or your enthusiasm for getting into unfamiliar
territory.

Comment: Thanks! I have one more question: as far as I understand, discriminant analysis for the case of 2 classes (with learning samples from normal distributions with equal variances) and unknown prior probabilities is basically equivalent to binary logistic regression: in both methods a point (x_1, x_2) is classified as belonging to the first class if b_1*x_1+b_2*x_2>c. It seems that the only difference between regression and discriminant analysis is that different techniques are used for estimation of b_1, b_2 and c. Am I right or no?

Comment: The two methods may coincide as you mention. However, discriminant analysis is mostly used with more than two classes.  Also, assumptions can be quite different between LDA and logistic regression. In many cases, there is a prior for LDA. E.g., if one is trying to classify a humanoid scull bone as to 'race', the prior may differ vastly depending on the location of the site where the bone was found. Finally, much discriminant analysis is not linear. Even in 2-space there can be strangely shape data clouds that are easily separated by quadratic curves, but not by lines.